# Django + subprocess + php

Tags: php, django, apache2, subprocess, mod-wsgi

Есть функция:

```
def ExecutePhp(param):
    f = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "old_sc/script.php")
    command = 'php %s %s' % (f,param)
    process = subprocess.Popen([command, '-q'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    return out
```

На машине разработчика (под Debug) работает прекрасно. 
При переносе на сервер apache2 + mod_wsgi ругается:

> ```
> Could not open input file: /var/www/site/old_sc/script.php
> ```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось банально...

Не правильно были выставлены права на директорию  old_sc (может, кому пригодится)

```
chmod 555 old_sc
```